# Import an XMI file to a XML project Error : Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte utf-8 sequence

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, ansi, xmi

When I import my file XMI to my UML project (java project) I got a messege error

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException :  Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte utf-8 sequence.
```

In my file I used ANSI before, I rewrite in the file XMI.

I have no idea what's happened, someone could help me ?

Comment: Are you getting stacktrace that you can post here. May be it will provide better chances of root causing.

Comment: @Ayusman Sorry, I don't have it

Comment: I guess your XMI file is not UTF-8 encoded, but has another encoding instead (may be ISO-8859-1). In that case you would need an XML declaration as first line like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`. If this is missing the encoding is assumed to be UTF-8.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Hey Thomas, it works but why ?

Comment: It works because every XML-parser evaluates this line.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Ok thanks man ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML file is not UTF-8 encoded, then you need an [XML declaration](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd) as first line giving the actual encoding. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```